# Android DOM parsing is tooo slow

Tags: android, android-parser

I am trying to parse an web response with DOM parser like this:

```
public static Document parseDocument(InputStream sr) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbf.setIgnoringComments(true);
    dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    dbf.setCoalescing(true);
    //dbf.setValidating(false);
    Document xdoc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(sr));
    xdoc.normalize();
    return xdoc;
}
```

The problem is that

```
Document xdoc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(sr));
```

takes 3 min to be executed. My xml file has 3800 lines.
Is than normaé and how to improve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too big for DOM parsing in android. Memory consumption and object allocation is porhobitive.  SAX asin previous answer is  workable solution, but Pull-Parser ( also contained in android APIs )  is better and more modern choice, as it is easier to program 
( with SAX  parser drives procesing and pushes XML events ti your handler,  while XPP it is your application driving parser and pulling xml events out  of stream )

Even better choice would be some lightweight data binding framework built on top of pull parser - jackson, xstream etc. They will deliver just objects - s you do not have to worry about xml parsing at all

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Where could I find a suitable example of Pull-Parser please?